# How to authorize to spotify with Ruby + RestClient

Tags: ruby, spotify, watir, rest-client

I need to authorize and parse some data from my account.
When I try to accest authorize link im getting a set of error which I dont know how to handle.

```
require 'json'
require 'watir'
require 'bundler'
require 'rest-client'

#redirect_uri = ""
CLIENT_ID= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

puts(RestClient.get 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=%s' % [CLIENT_ID])
```

OUTPUT:

```
C:\Ruby30-x64\bin\ruby.exe C:/Users/Lil-Dredd/RubymineProjects/untitled/main.rb
<internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types/logger.rb:26: _1 is reserved for numbered parameter (SyntaxError)
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types/logger.rb:26: _2 is reserved for numbered parameter
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types/logger.rb:26: _3 is reserved for numbered parameter
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types/deprecations.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mime-types-2.99.3/lib/mime/types/columnar.rb:147:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rest-client-2.1.0-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient/request.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rest-client-2.1.0-x64-mingw32/lib/restclient.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rest-client-2.1.0-x64-mingw32/lib/rest-client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:160:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:160:in `rescue in require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:149:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Lil-Dredd/RubymineProjects/untitled/main.rb:4:in `<main>'
<internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- rest-client (LoadError)
        from <internal:C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Lil-Dredd/RubymineProjects/untitled/main.rb:4:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I authorize to spotify with rest client in ruby? :(

Comment: It seems to me that mime-types 2.X does not support ruby >= 2.7. You'll have to upgrade mime-types

Comment: How can I do this ?